# get free string genre id3-tag and not only genre number in bash script

Tags: shell-script, software-rec, music, tagging

I'd like to read the id3-genre tag within a bash script.

I tried id3tool, eyeD3, etc -- but these tools just support the genre number. How to get the free string genre tag?

My music players (Amarok, VLC, Banshee) and the Android player show the full genre tag, so the tag itself seems intact.

Comment: What does `eyeD3` give you? I can see an arbitrary text string as `genre`: `eyeD3 foo.mp3 | grep genre | cut -f 3` returns `genre: foobar (id None)`

Comment: It gives me nothing. If I leave the grep away and look at the full eyeD3 output it doesn't show any genre tag. Could it be something about id3v2.4 vs id3v2.3?

Comment: UPDATE: id3v2.4 is not showing up at all. With id3v2.3 it works like pointed out here.